# How to find a property in a function

Tags: javascript

I want to know whether a function has a specific property.
the 'in' operator should have done the work:
MSD quote:

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

So - Can you please explain the result of this code?

````
function Shape() {
  aaa = 10
}
Shape.prototype.bbb = 20

function Square() {}
Square.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;

console.log('aaa' in Shape) // false???
console.log('bbb' in Shape) // false???
console.log('aaa' in Square) // false???
console.log('bbb' in Square) // false???```
````

Comment: You wouldn't do `'aaa' in Shape`, you would do `var x = new Shape(); 'aaa' in x`

Comment: I want to ask it on the function, not the object created by the function

Comment: and this should have worked as a function is also an object

Comment: Yes, a function is also an object, and that object doesn't have an `'aaa'` property, or `bbb`, or any of the other ones

Comment: Yes it does - in it's property chain - so the MSD quote applies to this case too

Comment: It clearly doesn't, because your `in` check is coming out as false

Comment: You've confused the `prototype` property of the functions (a regular property, whose value is used as the `[[Prototype]]` of the objects created by it), with the `[[Prototype]]` internal property (aka. `__proto__`, the 'real' prototype, the one which property lookups are based on, not directly accessible by JS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` doesn't check for the properties on `class` itself. It checks for properties in instance of a class.

```js
function Shape() {
  aaa = 10
}
Shape.prototype.bbb = 20

function Square() {}
Square.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;
const instance = new Square();
console.log('aaa' in instance) // false
console.log('bbb' in instance) // true
```

Here when you assign properties to prototype of certain `function` it doesn't mean that function will have those properties. Those properties on prototypes are add to the instances created by objects.

Yes if you assign property to function itself then it will show using `in`

```js
function test(){

}
test.prototype.x = 3;
test.something = 5
console.log(Object.keys(test)) //["something"]
console.log("something" in test) //true
```

Comment: There is no 'class' here. only functions, which are also objects - so this should have worked

Comment: @DuduArbel I have added the second part. If still any question feel free to ask

Comment: @DuduArbel And here function is just working as class.

Comment: Let me refine my question. I have a function. can I know whether a property is defined **in any way** on an instance of this function **without creating the instance**

Comment: @DuduArbel There is no single method for that. You will have to use `"property" in func || "property" in func.prototype`.